# Transform parent element to look concave, also transforming its children respectively

Tags: css, 3d, transform, concave

I'm trying to achieve a concave transformation in css to look like these examples (only HUD): [image]
<sub>(source: [pke6.de](https://pke6.de/uploads/Unbenannt-2.png))</sub>

[image]

I already tried to use skew, however, a skew into 2 directions would be necessary, which does not exist.

Another attempt is to split the left and right side into seperate sections, transforming them separately (not shown on the screenshot). However even that didn't quite look like the bottom left HUD element on the 2nd screenshot.

Is there any way to accomplish such an effect?

Comment: There is no way you can make a whole flat interface and then just apply a blanket transform to a parent element to give the whole thing a concave look. No such method of transform exists. You'd have to either fake each element individually (e.g., for the gray background shape in the first picture, maybe using `clip-path` on a gray rectangle) or create the correct shapes in the first place (e.g., in the first image, each of the gray boxes with green outlines could be a `background-image`).